# run php code on phpFiddle

Tags: php

I am new to php and got a silly question to ask. I am trying to get result displayed on this site but it was blank, did I do anything wrong, was php code tested differently than javascript? How do you run the function you created with variables and display the result? Do I just put down the function name with variable values and then hit run php??

```
  <?php
   function isVow(array $a)
    {
       return str_replace(['97', '101', '105', '111', '117'], ['a', 'e','i', 'o', 'u'], $a);

     }

      isVow(['97','101']);

     ?>
```

Comment: in this function you just return the result if you want to print this one use print_r or var_dump function.

Comment: This code does generate a blank page. You're not outputting anything. Try `var_dump(isVow(['97','101']));` to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 function isVow(array $a)
 {
     print_r(str_replace(['97', '101', '105', '111', '117'], ['a', 'e','i', 'o', 'u'], $a));
 }

 isVow(['97','101']);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tried echo(isVow(['97','101'])) before, hahah. but thanks anyways